# Really simple reading XML values. c++

Tags: c++, xml

I have a simple little bit of code to read a value held in an XML file. 
I have loaded the XML file and sorted the data to only show one value, but I can't seem to get it to work as I expect. At the moment it is only listing the Element name not the element value. I must be forgetting to read the value or something similar.
( XML is simple   )

> ```
> <Name>USERNAME</Name>
> ```

```
while (xreader->Read())
                        {
                                switch (xreader->NodeType)
                                {
                                case XmlNodeType::Element:
                                    {
                                        if (xreader->Name->Equals("Name"))
                                        {
                                                listBox1->Items->Add(xreader->Name);
                                                listBox1->Items->Add(xreader->Value);
                                        }                                           
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                    xreader->Close();
```

Comment: Run your program under the debugger, and look at "xreader" before you call your switch.  I'll betcha' the "type" is probably something other than "XmlNodeType::Element" ;)  Debuggers are your friends - definitely familiarize yourself with them.  IMHO...

Comment: Q: Did you figure it out?  Was the element type XmlNodeType::Text?  If you're using MS Visual Studio, it should be easy to find in the debugger.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

In the end I passed all of the data into a set of variables and sorted it from there. 
It seemed like the easier way to do it than deal directly with the data as it came in via xreader.